# Nexus 5 battery inaccurate

Tags: battery, nexus-5, battery-life

My Nexus 5 is very inaccurate with its battery life, it will usually die at about 90-85% but occasionally it goes to ~40% before dying. is there anyway for me to tell it "Hey! You have 0% battery, fix it!" and "Your battery isn't full yet, charge some more" without root?

Comment: Deleting my answer as it doesn't seem to match device

Comment: jut reakised theres a hidden logs thing...

Comment: nope, didnt work, just shows logs...

Comment: it shows like 5 logs with dates and 1 "Latest_Log"  when i hit the latest one and long press, nothing happens

Comment: i think im gonna close my post in a day or so if no one comes with ANY real ideas

Comment: That's your choice but expecting immediate workable solutions is wildly optimistic

Comment: There are a few things you can do. First wipe the cache partition. To do this, reboot your device into recovery mode, scroll to “Wipe Data/Factory reset” and click the “Wipe Cache Partition” option. The simple old-fashioned option to reset your battery is to let it drain completely, until it stops working. Then recharge till the point it's completely full. Repeat this a few times and this should re-calibrate the battery. If this does not work, it could just be that your battery is dying. The "your battery isn't full yet, charge some more" I do not recognize. This might suggest a faulty battery

Comment: Also, try another charger and see if you get the "your battery isn't full yet, charge some more" message still. If that doesn't help, try A PC as well.

Comment: found the issue, N5 batterys get "Mushy" and need replacement, replacing worked

Answer (score 0):

Buying new battery worked, N5 batterys can get "Mushy" or "Swollen" so replacement is key.

Buying new batteries is easy off of amazon and theres a billion youtube tutorials.